# Cannot be explicitly specialized

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2910   'addingStuff::addingStuffFunc':
>   cannot be explicitly
>   specialized   BuckysTemplateSpecialization    c:\users\amanuel\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\projects\buckystemplatespecialization\buckystemplatespecializ

When I try to run this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

template<class F, class S>
class addingStuff {
public:
    addingStuff(F fCons, S sCons) : f(fCons), s(sCons){}

    F addingStuffFunc();

private:
    F f; S s;
};

template<class F, class S>
F addingStuff<F, S>::addingStuffFunc() {
    return(f + s);
}

template<>
class addingStuff<std::string , std::string>{
public:
    addingStuff(std::string sConst, std::string s2Const):s(sConst), s2(s2Const){}   
    std::string addingStuffFunc();
private:
    std::string s, s2;
};

template<>
std::string addingStuff<std::string, std::string>::addingStuffFunc() {
    return "Sorry.. Adding strings is Illegal!!";
}

int main() {
    addingStuff<std::string, std::string> exampleStuff("Hello " , "World");
    std::cout << exampleStuff.addingStuffFunc() << std::endl;
}
```

No Clue Why..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just want:

```
std::string addingStuff<std::string, std::string>::addingStuffFunc() {
    return "Sorry.. Adding strings is Illegal!!";
}
```

The extra `template <>` gets interpreted as the template-id for the member function, and the code gets interpreted as an explicit specialiation of it for `<>`. But `addingStuffFunc` isn't a function template, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! Ill accept the anwser in 5minutes(minumum time).. But one more question! Why do i do template<class F, class S>  for the first function, and i just let it out for the second function? Is it because its actually specialized to a specific data-type? Thankyou

Comment: @Dsafds Pretty much.